# Can cats get depressed in a way similar to humans?

Tags: depression

Most of the research on depression seems quite human focused. Can cats also get depressed in the same way there's depression for humans?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Human depression has been modeled in a variety of animal models, including cats ([Wilner, 1984](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00427414)). Cats show comparable signs of distress when subject to maternal separation, including separation phenomena of protest, followed by despair. Although it is hard to project the DSM-V criteria onto cats, they can show comparable behaviors when subject to anxiety and stress.

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Wilner, *Psychoneuropharmacol* (1984); **83**(1): 1-16](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00427414)</sub>

Answer (score 6):

There is a lot of research on depression in animals.

Wikipedia has a [good summary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_models_of_depression#Modeling_depression_in_animals) of the comparison of depression between animals and humans:

> It is difficult to develop an animal model that perfectly reproduces
>   the symptoms of depression in patients. Many animals lack
>   self-consciousness, self-reflection, and consideration; moreover,
>   hallmarks of the disorder such as depressed mood, low self-esteem or
>   suicidality are hardly accessible in non-humans. However, depression,
>   as other mental disorders, consists of endophenotypes[5] that can be
>   reproduced independently and evaluated in animals.
>
> The following endophenotypes have been described:[5]
>
> - Anhedonia: The loss of interest is a core symptom of depression.
> - Anhedonia in rodents can be assessed by sucrose preference or by
>     intracranial self-stimulation.
> - Behavioral despair: Behavioral despair might be assessed with tests such as the forced-swimming test or the tail suspension test.
> - Changes in appetite or weight gain: Depression is often associated with changes in appetite or weight gain, which is easily measured in
>     rodents.
> - Neuroanatomy: Depressed subjects display decreased hippocampal volume and rodents exposed to chronic stress or excess glucocorticoids
>     exhibit similar signs of hippocampal loss of neurons and dendritic
>     atrophy.
> - Neuroendocrine disturbances: Disturbances of the hypothalamic–pituitary–adrenal axis (HPA) are one of the most
>     consistent symptoms in major depression. The functionality of the HPA
>     can be assessed by dexamethasone suppression test .
> - Alterations in sleep architecture: Disturbances in the circadian rhythm and especially in the sleep architecture are often observed in
>     depressed. In rodents, it is accessible via
>     electroencephalography(EEG).
> - Anxiety-related behavior: Anxiety is a symptom with high prevalence in depression. Therefore, animal models of depression often display
>     altered anxiety-related behavior.

One of the early popular models of depression based on animal behaviour is [learned helplessness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learned_helplessness) theory:

> Learned helplessness theory is the view that clinical depression and
>   related mental illnesses may result from a perceived absence of
>   control over the outcome of a situation.

This has been replicated in many animals, including cats. (A nice review of learned helplessness in humans [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YMPzDiraNnA).)

[Modern theories of depression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_depressive_disorder#Causes) include many other causes besides learning, not all of which are applicable to animals.  So ultimately, cats do get depressed, in a way similar in some respects to humans, but in other aspects, not the same.

Comment: I say that animals have the same emotions as humans, just somewhat different reasons for them.